# Can $k$ be arbitrarily large in the following equations?

Tags: nt.number-theory, perfect-numbers

(Note: This question was cross-posted from [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2201682) per Dris's request.)

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number in Eulerian form.  (That is, $q$ is prime with $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.  Note that $q \geq 5$.)  The Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli conjecture for odd perfect numbers predicts that $k=1$ always holds.

I believe it is currently unknown whether $k$ can be bounded from above, but the following appears to be a viable approach for this problem:

Consider the expression
$$N - (q^k + n^2) + 1 = (q^k - 1)(n^2 - 1) = (q - 1)\sigma(q^{k-1})(n + 1)(n - 1).$$

The reason for the $\sigma(q^{k-1})$ term is because of the following expression in this [preprint](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.01868.pdf), which gives:
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))=\frac{2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)}{\sigma(q^{k-1})}$$
which would then be equal to
$$\frac{(q - 1)(n + 1)(n - 1)(2n^2 - \sigma(n^2))}{N - (q^k + n^2) + 1},$$
from which it follows that
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}\cdot\bigg[N - (q^k + n^2) + 1\bigg]=\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}\cdot\bigg[N - (q^k + n^2) + 1\bigg]$$
$$=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))\cdot\bigg[N - (q^k + n^2) + 1\bigg]=(q-1)(n+1)(n-1)(2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)).$$

Now, it is conjectured that $q^k < n$ (see this [M. Sc. thesis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.1450.pdf) and this [paper](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.pdf)).  This will then imply that
$$\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}>\frac{8n^2}{5q^k}>\frac{8n}{5}>\frac{8}{5}\cdot{\sqrt[3]{N}}$$
since $\sigma(q^k)/q^k  < 5/4$ holds for all $k$.  Hence, by using [Ochem and Rao](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2012-81-279/S0025-5718-2012-02563-4/S0025-5718-2012-02563-4.pdf)'s lower bound for the magnitude of an odd perfect number, we get that $N>{10}^{1500}$, so that
$$\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}>\frac{8}{5}\cdot{{10}^{500}}$$

Notice that in the equation
$$\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}\cdot\bigg[N - (q^k + n^2) + 1\bigg]=(q-1)(n+1)(n-1)(2n^2 - \sigma(n^2))$$
the *RHS* does not involve $k$.  Holding $q$ and $n$ constant (i.e. considering a specific Euler prime $q$ and a specific square root of non-Euler part $n$), and allowing $k$ to vary, then we have
$$\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}\cdot\bigg[N - (q^k + n^2) + 1\bigg]=(q-1)(n+1)(n-1)(2n^2 - \sigma(n^2))$$
$$> \frac{8}{5}\cdot{\sqrt[3]{N}}\cdot\bigg[N - (q^k + n^2) + 1\bigg]$$
$$\lim_{k \to \infty}{\bigg(\frac{8}{5}\cdot{\sqrt[3]{N}}\cdot\bigg[N - (q^k + n^2) + 1\bigg]\bigg)} \leq (q-1)(n+1)(n-1)(2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)),$$
from which we get the "*contradiction*"
$$(q-1)(n+1)(n-1)(2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)) \geq \lim_{k \to \infty}{\bigg(\frac{8}{5}\cdot{\sqrt[3]{N}}\cdot\bigg[N - (q^k + n^2) + 1\bigg]\bigg)} \to \infty.$$

Here are my questions:

> **(1)** Is there indeed a contradiction in the last step of this "*proof*" that $k$ is bounded from above?
>
> **(2)** Is it possible to make the argument in this "*proof*" more rigorous?

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  I asked Antalan to cross-post this question from MSE for me because I currently could no longer post questions in MO.

Comment: Additionally, kindly take note of my edit to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with Euler prime $q$.

Unconditionally, it is known that $q^k < n^2$ [[Dris, 2012]](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html).  This implies that $k$ and $n$ are dependent, which means that the proof in the question is flawed.

(This answer is based on [JonMark Perry](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/210189)'s in the hyperlinked [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2201682).)